# OSError: cannot load library 'libngspice.so': libngspice.so on GOOGLE-COLAB

Tags: google-colaboratory

I am trying to use PySpice on Google-Colab, but it is throwing this error.

`**OSError:** cannot load library 'libngspice.so': libngspice.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.  Additionally, ctypes.util.find_library() did not manage to locate a library called 'libngspice.so'`

*Note:* I have installed PySpice with this command.

```
!pip install PySpice
```

And, also tried with this command.

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/FabriceSalvaire/PySpice
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that you have not installed libngspice0 into the Colab instance. Since PySpice depends on this package, you'll have to install before being able to run any simulations.

In Colab, there are two easy ways I've highlighted below. I'd recommend the second option (using conda), since you'll likely face less dependency problems down the line.

**Option 1: Downloading and installing packages manually:**

```
# install libc-6-dev dependency
!apt update && apt -q install libc6-dev

# download libngspice0 packages from debian and install
!wget http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/ngspice/libngspice0_30.2-1~bpo9+1_amd64.deb && apt install -q ./libngspice0_30.2-1~bpo9+1_amd64.deb
!wget http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/ngspice/libngspice0-dev_30.2-1~bpo9+1_amd64.deb && apt install -q ./libngspice0-dev_30.2-1~bpo9+1_amd64.deb

# install pyspice using pip
!pip install pyspice
```

**Option 2: Using conda on Colab to install ngspice:**

Before you can use conda on Colab, you'll also need to install it. This is straightforward using condacolab:

```
!pip install -q condacolab
import condacolab
condacolab.install()
```

Once conda is installed, run the following:

```
# install ngspice packages, including executables & master package
!conda install -c conda-forge ngspice-exe  
!conda install -c conda-forge ngspice      
!conda install -c conda-forge ngspice-lib

# install pyspice using pip
!pip install pyspice
```

Once you've successfully run one of the above options, confirm the installation using the following:

```
!pyspice-post-installation --check-install
```

Provided the above runs without any problems, you should be good to go!